# How to update array in array in nested state in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to update an array in an array in react nested state. I already learned about shallow copies but don't get how to implement it in this case.

There is a dispatch function with the useReducer hook to manage an array of objects called "Layer"

```
interface Layer {
  name: string,
  data: Item[],
  ...
}
```

every Layer holds an array of Items

```
class Item {
  id: number;
  ...
}
```

this is my dispatch function:

```
type ActionType =
  | { type: "ADD LAYER"; layer: Layer }
  | { type: "ADD ITEM"; item: Item; layer: Layer }
  | { type: "UPDATE ITEM"; item: Item; layer: Layer }
  | { type: "REMOVE ITEM"; item: Item; layer: Layer };

 const [layers, dispatch] = useReducer((state: Layer[], action: ActionType) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD LAYER":
        {
          if (!state.includes(action.layer))
            state.push(action.layer);
          return state;
        }
      case "ADD ITEM":
        {
          if(!state.find(layer => layer.name === action.layer.name)?.data.find(item => item.id === action.item.id))
          state.find(layer => layer.name === action.layer.name)?.data.push(action.item)
          return state;
        }
      case "UPDATE ITEM": {
        //implementation missing
        return state;
      }
      case "REMOVE ITEM":
        {
          const newState = {
            ...state.map(layer =>
              layer.name == action.layer.name
                ? { ...layer, data: {
                  ...layer.data.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.item.id)
                } }
            : layer )
          };
          return newState;
        }
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }, initialLayers);
```

look at the `REMOVE ITEM` case to see what I tried. But this approach make my application crash with the message: `Uncaught TypeError: layers.map is not a function`

case `ADD LAYER` and `ADD ITEM` are working

Comment: Could you post the full error, because the code in your question is not doing in any place layers.map only layer.map, so I would like to see where you map layers?

Comment: There are three error messages in my console: "Uncaught TypeError: layers.map is not a function" and two times "Uncaught TypeError: layers.find is not a function"

Comment: Chrome has a more detailed error message saying also  " Warning: Cannot update a component (`LayersProvider`) while rendering a different component (`Layer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Layer`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render"

Comment: Could you post the full message then, just trying to see the stack to have a better context.

Comment: So.... did you follow the stack trace as described at that link?

Comment: @jean182: https://demo.hedgedoc.org/EdkWDRAGTHC_pXUGfBDYtQ#

Comment: I don't think is the reducer or only on it, by looking your stack trace is at Layer.tsx in line 17 and DynamicHeroIcon.tsx line 12, what are you doing in those two files?

Comment: I'm now handling Layers and Items in separate hooks and everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that?

```
case "REMOVE ITEM":
{
  let clonedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))

  const layerIndex = clonedState.findIndex(layer => layer.name == action.layer.name);
  
  if (layerIndex > -1) {
    if (clonedState[layerIndex].data.filter(d => d.id == action.item.id).length > 0)
      clonedState[layerIndex].data = clonedState[layerIndex].data.filter(d => d.id !== action.item.id)
  }

  return clonedState;
}
```

NOTE: You can also modify data array like below (which is more elegant)

```
const itemIndex = clonedState[layerIndex].data.findIndex(d => d.id == action.item.id)
clonedState[layerIndex].data = [
  ...clonedState[layerIndex].data.slice(0, itemIndex),
  ...clonedState[layerIndex].data.slice(itemIndex + 1),
]
```

instead of

```
clonedState[layerIndex].data = clonedState[layerIndex].data.filter(d => d.id !== action.item.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

State is an array of objects:

```
case "REMOVE ITEM": {
  const newState = {};
  return newState;  // <- return an object
}
```

But this is returning an single object, so this will not work.

As you are using `map()` function, and it will create a new array, you might as well do this instead:

```
case "REMOVE ITEM": {
  return state.map((layer) =>
        layer.name == action.layer.name
          ? {
              ...layer,
              data: {
                ...layer.data.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.item.id),
              },
            }
          : layer
      );
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work yet. The error message changed to: Uncaught TypeError: _b.map is not a function

Comment: This should work